# Condition in update with upsert: true

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have db structure as;

```
"name" : "alex"
"age" : "21"
"location" : "la"

"name" : "felix"
"age" : "1"
"location" : "la"
```

I want to update location field if name and age fields in the database are equal to the values in my query.

So for example if I wrote;

```
db.collection.update({name: "alex", age: "32"}, {$set: {location: "ny"}} ,{upsert: true})
```

it inserts new element as

```
name: alex
age: 32
```

However, what I want to do is; update `location` if `name` is `alex` and `age` is `21`. Deleting the `upsert` can be a solution, however, I use for both insert and update, so `upsert` shouldn't be deleted.

How can I handle this in the node.js side?

Edit: What I'm trying to do is;

```
db.collection.update({name: "alex", age: "32"}, {$set: {location: "ny"}} ,{upsert: true})
```

returns false, because alex is 21 years old. location cannot be set.

```
db.collection.update({name: "alex", age: "21"}, {$set: {location: "ny"}} ,{upsert: true})
```

sets the location.

```
"name" : "alex"
"age" : "21"
"location" : "la"
```

db becomes

```
"name" : "alex"
"age" : "21"
"location" : "ny"

"name" : "felix"
"age" : "1"
"location" : "la"
```

Comment: Sounds exactly like the upsert you're already using. Can you provide more details about what you're trying to do?

Comment: should't there be a comma between here `{$set: {location: "ny"}}, {upsert: true}` ?

Comment: I really can't understand the problem here. Also you have missing comma before the `upsert` option.

Comment: Edit the location when the age and name fields are match. If the age and name fields do not match, upsert adds new element with new age and name. I don't want this situation. Still can not explain? :(

Answer (score 0):

When there is upsert: true, then mongo add this field to all collection object (even creates new document), so when you don't have field location it will be created.
Upsert is considered in document scope instead of field scope.

```
db.collection.update({name: "alex", age: "21"}, {$set: {location: "ny"}})
```

Comment: I understand. But. I still want to add data if name age do not match. for example this one;  db.collection.update({name: "phoenix", age: "32"}, {$set: {location: "ny"}} ,{upsert: true})